# Limit download size in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

We're using RestSharp v105.2.3.

Is there a way to stop receiving a response after N bytes have been received, where N is a parameter I can control?

---

Edit: here is my complete solution based on Berin's answer below.

```
public static class IRestClientExtensions
{
    public static IRestResponse Execute(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, byte[] buffer, out int bufferSize)
    {
        var totalBytesRead = 0;

        request.ResponseWriter = stream =>
        {
            while (totalBytesRead < buffer.Length)
            {
                var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, buffer.Length - totalBytesRead);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
        };

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        bufferSize = totalBytesRead;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Unit tests (using NUnit):

```
[TestFixture]
public class IRestClientExtensionsTests
{
    [Test, Explicit]
    public void Execute_OutputBufferTooSmall()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html");
        var request = new RestRequest();

        var buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int bufferSize;
        var response = client.Execute(request, buffer, out bufferSize);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content));
        Assert.AreEqual(buffer.Length, bufferSize);
    }

    [Test, Explicit]
    public void Execute_OutputBufferLargeEnough()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html");
        var request = new RestRequest();

        var buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
        int bufferSize;
        var response = client.Execute(request, buffer, out bufferSize);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Content));
        Assert.IsTrue(bufferSize < buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a way, but you loose the ability of the `RestResponse` to pull the data and deserialize it automatically.  I believe the use case is more for pulling Blobs from the cloud:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);

request.ResponseWriter = (stream) => {
    // work with the writer you recieve here.
    // This is an Action<Stream> callback
};

// NOTE: the callback is invoked during this statement:
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

// The response has all the meta information, but none of the data.
```

The `ResponseWriter` property is an `Action<Stream>` callback.  The code that reads the HTTP response either calls `ResponseWriter` if it is provided, or it reads all the bytes at once and populates the `Response.RawBytes` property.

You have to choose which behavior you want.